# Inline formset factory - pass request to child form

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I'm facing a quite challenging taks:

I need an `inlineformset_factory` connecting my `ParentEntity` to my foreign key-bound `ChildEntities`.

My `ChildEntity` contains a foreign key relation I need to filter per logged-in user - so I need the request in the `ChildForm`.

What I've tried so far:

- I tried to use the `form=` kwarg but I can't pass an instance - just a class. So no way for me to add the request here.
- I tried to use the `formset=` kwarg but when I try to pass the `request=request` as a kwarg of the `inlineformset_factory` I get an error (Unexpected kwarg)

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes asking a colleague is even faster than `StackOverflow` :)

Here's my solution:

**forms.py**

```
class BaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)

    super(BaseFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ParentEntity, ChildEntity, formset=BaseFormSet, form=ChildForm, extra=2, max_num=max_num, can_delete=False)
...
formset = MyFormSet(request.POST, instance=obj, request=request)
```

Comment: were you able to get request in ChildForm ?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it this way:

```
MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ParentEntity, ChildEntity, formset=BaseFormSet, form=ChildForm, extra=1)

formset = MyFormSet(form_kwargs={'request': request})
```

Then on your ChildForm:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(ChildForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```