# Django pass variable/param to modelform formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have been digging around and I can't seem to find an answer to my problem

Basically, if you want to pass parameters/variables to a form you do this:

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg')
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And pass the param like this in views:

```
def someview(request):
    form = SomeForm(request.POST, my_arg=somevalue)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    else:
        form = SomeForm(my_arg=somevalue)

     return render(....)
```

However I am using `inlineformset_factory` and i am getting an error:

`__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'my_arg'`

If I try to pass it like this:

```
myformset = inlineformset_factory(modelA, modelB, form=SomeForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)

def someview(request):
    form = myformset(request.POST, my_arg=somevalue)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    else:
        form = SomeForm(my_arg=somevalue)

     return render(....)
```

I am using [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) to generate my forms dynamically(django 1.8)

Did I miss something or am I doing it wrong? If so, what would be a plausible solution?

**UPDATE**

I tried doing

```
class BaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_arg = kwargs.pop("my_arg")
        super(BaseFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

then adding `formset = BaseFormSet` in:

```
myformset = inlineformset_factory(modelA, modelB, formset = BaseFormSet, form=SomeForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
```

while I am not getting an error form `BaseFormSet`, how do I get the `my_arg` to SomeForm? And I am also getting an error:

```
KeyError at /someurl
'my_arg'

    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
    Django Version: 1.8.2
    Exception Type: KeyError
    Exception Value: 'my_arg'
    Exception Location: ..../forms.py in __init__, line 108(the my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg') line)
    Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
    Python Version: 2.7.10
    Python Path:    
    ['C:\\Users\\lolwat\\Desktop\\ITSWEBSITE',
     'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
     'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
     'C:\\Python27',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I did not change anything from my code except adding the `BaseFormSet`

I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875555/inline-formset-factory-pass-request-to-child-form)

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Comment: What happens if you add a default value for pop, ie. `self.my_arg = kwargs.pop("my_arg", None)`?